# Changing self display of User in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I would like to see the user.email instead of the user.username when print(user) is called. This is to say that in my admin, i would like to see the emails as foreign keys.

Normally i would do in the following way as described on the [django tutorial](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/):

```
class Poll(models.Model):
# ...
def __unicode__(self):
    return self.question
```

However, User class is prewritten and i don't want to mod Django. How then should i proceed?

UPDATE:
I added the following to my Model:

```
def email(self):
    u = User.object.get(pk=self.user.id)
    return u.email
```

How do i tie it to my list_display now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define a method on your Poll class called 'get_username' or something, that returns the email address of the user instead of their actual username. Then pass 'get_username' as a parameter to your 'list_display' attribute in the ModelAdmin of your Poll class.

Comment: thanx, i added a code, can you help me tie it to the list_display?

Comment: Why do you need help with that? Just add the name.

Comment: I tried added like so in the admin.py `list_display('id', 'email')` but it wouldn't work. I had to move the entire PollAdmin class definition to the models.py and it now works. I don't know if this is bad practice, but this was the only way i got it to work

Comment: You can change your function to just the following line 'return self.user.email'. You then just add in the name of the function to the list_display. When you say it didn't work before, what do you mean? Did it not show at all? If it didn't show at all then that is a sign that your admin was not being registered perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

The use-case you define requires overriding the `User.__unicode__` method.

From the django docs on [list_display](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display):

> If the field is a ForeignKey, Django will display the `__unicode__()` of the related object.

I can't see any way around this.